# API which provide data from Elastic Search and not SQL

Tags: sql, api, elasticsearch

I have a system where there are large dataset(s) where I want to have quick searches, and elastic search is suitable for it. So the data resides in SQL, and is synced to ES. There is an obvious small delay in this sync.

There are consumers of this data which could work with slightly stale data. So if there's an API for UI which end users use to see the dataset. A delay of 3-4 seconds is acceptable. So API handler which deals with ES is perfect here.

Then there are consumers of this data (bots) who want to work with real time data. So for the almost same requirements, should I create another API just like that in UI consumer, which gets data from SQL?

What is the usual best practice which is followed, and I'm assuming this is a very common usecase.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should stick to creating just a sinlge API and use a query string parameter to decide which of the two data sources to use. This will result in less code to maintain.